# MySQL: alternate to left join over three tables

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have three tables with the following structure.

> **Table child**
>
> ID , Name, ....
>
> 3,  John, ...
>
> 5, erik,....
>
> 7, Maya

The child id is related to teacher in the 2nd table.

> Table teacher_child_relation
>
> id, child_id, teacher_id
>
> 1, 3(john), 4(roberts)
>
> 2, 5(erik), 9(maria)

The teachers details are in the third table.

> Table teacher
>
> id, Name,....
>
> 4, Roberts
>
> 9, Maria

Now I am running the following query to get the Named of teacher assigned to a child. I am using the following query.

```
SELECT c.*, t.name,
FROM child c, teacher_child_relation ct, teacher t
WHERE c.id = ct.child_id AND ct.teacher_id = t.id
```

This returns me only those records of children who are assigned a teacher. I want a query that returns all the records of child and show an empty field where teacher is not assigned.

Comment: Try to avoid comma seperated JOINS!

Comment: I would suggest you to go with [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) wherein you can [generate the above query](http://sqlyogkb.webyog.com/article/186-the-sqlyog-query-builder) with just few clicks and it also provides the option for join on tables, thus eliminating the need to remember the syntax of sql statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) This gives all the children info regardless of teacher assigned or not assigned to the child,

```
SELECT c.`id` AS `child_od`,c.`Name` AS `child_name`,t.`Name` AS `teacher_name`
FROM child c
LEFT JOIN teacher_child_relation tc ON c.`id`=tc.`child_id`
LEFT JOIN teacher t ON tc.`teacher_id`=t.`id`;
```

2) This gives info of only the child assigned to the teacher,

```
SELECT c.`id` AS `child_id`,c.`Name` AS `child_name`,t.`Name` AS `teacher_name`
FROM child c
JOIN teacher_child_relation tc ON c.`id`=tc.`child_id`
JOIN teacher t ON tc.`teacher_id`=t.`id`;
```

I would suggest you to go with [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) wherein you can [generate the above query](http://sqlyogkb.webyog.com/article/186-the-sqlyog-query-builder) with just few clicks and it also provides the option for join on tables, thus eliminating the need to remember the syntax of sql statements.
[image]

Comment: If you very seldom write queries, this sounds like a good tool. If you have to construct queries every now and then I would really advise to learn writing SQL and especially understanding the logic behind it. I think the difference between a `inner join` and a `left join` stays important in every tool.

Comment: Yes..I would agree on "If you very seldom write queries, this sounds like a good tool". Also IMO even as an pro in sql,you can still use it as it saves your time in writing the queries also avoiding syntax mistakes. @flaschenpost

Answer (score 2):

First: you will get several rows for a single child with all its teachers, I am not sure if you are aware of this.

Second: What against a nice left join?

```
select c.*, t.name
from child c
left join teacher_child_relation ct on ct.child_id = c.id
left join teacher t on t.id = ct.teacher_id
```

You could also try to list every child only once and getting a concatenated List of all teachers for this child. It depends on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT child.ID, child.Name, teacher.Name
FROM child
LEFT JOIN teacher_child_relation ON child.Id = teacher_child_relation.child_id
LEFT JOIN teacher ON teacher.id = teacher_child_relation.teacher_id;
```

Comment: this will not provide all childs instead provide only matching rows.